# Change input mode for TimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, material-components-android, android-timepicker

I saw from the [documentation](https://material.io/components/time-pickers), there explained that we could change the input mode, for example the script:

```
builder.setInputMode (MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_TEXT);
```

So, how can I change the input mode using the TimePickerDialog class?

Basically I want to make the default as shown below:

[image]

I use fragments when calling TimePickerDialog, like this:

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),
                (view13, hourOfDay, minute1) -> {
                    String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute1);
                    viewModel.setTimeIn(time);
                },
                Integer.parseInt(hour), Integer.parseInt(minute), false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the new **`MaterialTimePicker`** included in the Material Components Library.

```
val materialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .setInputMode(MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
    .build()

materialTimePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "fragment_tag")
```

[image]

**Note:** this code requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha03`**.